# How do Storyboards Push Nested Navigation Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

A storyboard allows me to setup a nested navigation controller with a push segue (and it works fine):

[image]
[image]

But if I try and do it without a segue in code, I (expectedly) throw an error:

> 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

```
@IBAction func showTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let secondNav = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondNavID") else { return }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondNav, animated: true)
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to reproduce the above storyboard behavior in code (without a segue), but I'm not sure what it's doing.

Is the storyboard defaulting to "present" even though it's set it to "show"?

Answer (score 0):

Although a storyboard may seem to permit nested nav controllers, that configuration is illegal outside a collapsed split view controller and should never be used (according to Apple).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screen grab of both a "Show" and a "Present Modal" so this seems to be the case that the storyboard is just reverting back to a Present for a navigation controller:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/00t2Y.jpg

It seems as if the best solution is to remove any "Show" segues and replace with "Present"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could *present* the navigation controller instead of pushing, therefore you will should have the hierarchy as:

Nav Controller embeds view controller => **presents** Nav Controller embeds view controller.